# PHP executing external commands - how to when username and password required

Tags: php, exec

Okay so I want to change the file mode of a directory to 777 so I use the line

```
exec('chmod -R 777' . $dir);
```

where $dir is the directory path of the directory I wanna change

it doesn't seem to work but I don't get an error for it, also if the user I was executing the script from was a sudo user so I have to enter the password after I enter the command, how would I do this? Would it be something like    `exec('chmod -R 777' . $dir\n 'password');` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Information I get from this [site](http://exain.wordpress.com/2007/11/24/execute-system-commands-via-php/)

**Execute system commands via PHP**

Many a times we need to execute system commands on a Linux system – to delete a directory, or restart a service. However, since Apache does not run with root privileges, it is nearly impossible to use PHP’s exec(), system() or passthru() functions to achieve that.

The solution to this is very simple, specially on Ubuntu. The Apache’s user www-data need to be granted privileges to execute certain applications using sudo.

1.Run the command `sudo visudo`

2.At the end of the file, add the following

`www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/iptables, /usr/bin/du`

This is assuming that you wish to run iptables and du using super user (root) privileges. However, if you wish to run every application using super user privileges, then add the following instead of what’s above

`www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL`

3.That’s it, now use `exec()` in the following manner inside your .php script

`exec ("sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT");`

Comment: Here I just copy pasted that site content because even if the link broken this may helpful.

Comment: @seanyt123 If this answer solved your problem please accept the answer this may increase the quality answer in stackoverflow by clicking tick mark just below the vote down symbol.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Server 22.04, and this is not working. IT used to work for me in Ubuntu Server 16.04. Can anybody help me with this?